# How to modify arrayFormula and vlookup in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I'm just new in Google Apps Script. I want to modify this formula below to Google Apps Script

```
=arrayFORMULA(iferror(VLOOKUP(J3,{'WO SR 22/23'!P:P,'WO SR 22/23'!B:B},2,FALSE)))
```

The lookup value is in wsPetitionStatusReport sheet. I tried code below but it always return null. Can you help me with this? Thank you so much

```
function vLookUpVALUE() {

   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const wsWOSR = ss.getSheetByName("WO SR 22/23")
const wsPetitionStatusReport  = ss.getSheetByName("Petition Status Report ")
 
const searchVALUES = wsPetitionStatusReport.getRange("J3:J").getValues()


const wsWOSRDATcolO = wsWOSR.getRange("B3:P" + wsWOSR.getLastRow()).getValues();


const matchDATAcolO = searchVALUES.map(searchROWcolO => {
        const matchROWcolO = wsWOSRDATcolO.find (r => r[0] == searchROWcolO[0])
        return matchROWcolO ? [matchROWcolO[0]] : [null]
    
})
  
 console.log(matchDATAcolO)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate the array formula for the whole column by replacing `J3` with an open-ended reference like `J3:J`:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(J3:J, { 'WO SR 22/23'!P:P, 'WO SR 22/23'!B:B }, 2, false)))`

To do the same with Apps Script, use something like this:

```js
function vlookupLookAlike() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = {
    values: ss.getRange('WO SR 22/23!B3:P').getValues(),
    keyColumn: 14, // =column(P3) - column(B3)
    dataColumn: 0,
  };
  source.keys = source.values.map(row => row[source.keyColumn]);
  source.data = source.values.map(row => row[source.dataColumn]);
  const target = {
    range: ss.getRange('Petition Status Report !J3:J'), // trailing space
  };
  target.keys = target.range.getValues().flat();
  target.results = target.keys.map(key => [key && source.data[source.keys.indexOf(key)]]);
  target.range.offset(0, 5).setValues(target.results);
}
```

Comment: I want to get the values in B3:B column by the lookupvalue in another sheet which is in J3:J. I had already a code of this but my problem is I can't map the values if the column is reverse

Comment: Anyway, can you explain me this line

target.keys = target.range.getValues().flat();

and this line too

  target.results = target.keys.map(key => [key && source.data[source.keys.indexOf(key)]]);

Thank you..

Comment: See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Comment: @Tedinoz Is there another solution for that?

Comment: @EnriqueFerolino I don't understand you - another solution for what? BTW, I just noticed that your original code DOES include the `map` method. You don't use `flat` but the built-in function `flatten` flattens all the values from one or more ranges into a single column, and `flat` does the same in apps script.

Comment: @Tedinoz So, you said I just want to add flat function in my code in order the map method works?

Comment: @EnriqueFerolino No - we are at cross purposes. 1) You asked doubleunary to explain why how those two lines of code worked. 2) I suggested to doubleunary that this was a reasonable request, 3) Then I noticed that your own code used `map` - so you'll be familiar with that method - so I deleted my comment to doubleunary. 4) That just left an explanation for `flat` and I tried to do that myself in my comment above. 5) I don't have another solution; if the solution by doubleunary doesn't work, then you should tell him.

Comment: @Tedinoz Is that so. I'm not really familiar with apps script or javascript. And for that map method I just learned that with doing some research. 2) Anyway, I observe that code of doubleunary is displaying the result so slow.

Comment: There is nothing special to the two lines of code. I think it is a reasonable expectation that an OP that posts an Apps Script question is capable of looking up basic `Array` methods such as `.map()`. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Comment: @doubleunary Hi, Good day, Can I ask additional for this thread? What if I have to add a IF ELSE statement of what the values result of .map(). Example, if every values on .map() result is empty or contains "N/A" text. Then it will setValues to that sheet.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). You may want to post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).